# how to add html5 code in mvc3 website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

i want to add piece of html5 code to my mvc3 website, im posting the code that i want to add below

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

but when im typing the video tag, im not getting it in intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 you can install the [Web Standards Update](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83?SRC=VSIDE).

Comment: You should have a "Html Source editing" toolbar available. In that toolbar there is a dropdownlist where you can select HTML5 or XHTML5.

Comment: once i select will that be default for all the projects in visual studio or i should keep on selecting each time i start a new project?